# Visio 2010 Shape Data 

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

I just started using Visio last week and have network items mapped out and their information entered in the shape data for each item.  My question is this, is there a way to export the shape data that I entered in to an excel spread sheet.  For example: I have a 42 port switch and have all 42 ports entered in the shape data.

I would like to export that info to excel so I don't have to type it again in excel.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a report based on shape data is a built-in feature of Visio.

In the Visio 2010 ribbon, select **Review** tab and then click **Shape Reports**

[image]

Then select a report you want to run and click **Run**

[image]

Then select the output format you want and click OK

[image]

If you selected Excel, then Excel will start with report data

[image]

Notice that you can modify or create new kinds of reports to meet your particular needs.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the help!